# angular 2: pass a HTML Element to template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

The data source I get passed something like:

```
<a href="javascript:blahblah...>Something</a>
```

And I assigned it to say `anchor: HTMLAnchorElement;` in the component. When I try to display it in template like this:

```
{{anchor}}
```

It comes out as `javascript:0 blehblahek`.

What I want to do is just pass that HTML Element to the template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for `innerHTML`, for example:

**Component**

```
someHtmlCode: string = "<div><b>This is my HTML.</b></div>"
```

**Template**

```
<div [innerHTML]="someHtmlCode"></div>
```

But, if you want to pass `script` tag or some other potentially dangerous code, you need to use [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html).